# AVR C++ will not compare numbers

Tags: c++, if-statement, binary, boolean, avr

I've been writing a small library for Arduino that essentially gives me control over timer 0 (yes I know the delay() function uses this timer). I started to notice an issue in the code though. The pre-scaler value is passed through the function when it is called along with a few other things: attachTimeInterrupt(int ttc, int prescaler, void (*f)()). In this function, I have a few if statements that determine if the pre-scaler is equal to a few values, being: 1, 8, 64, 256, 1024. Even if the pre-scaler value is set to one of these numbers, the if statement will still not trigger. The proper ISR for this function does, however trigger if a default pre-scaler is set. Here is my code for that function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void TimerZero::attachTimeInterrupt(int ttc, int prescaler, void (*f)()){
    DDRB = 0b11111111;

    prescaler = 1; //Even if I set this right here, it will still not work.

    if(prescaler == 1){
        PORTB = 0b11111111; //This tests to see if it has been called
        TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00) | (1 << WGM02);

    } else if(prescaler == 8) {

        TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01) | (1 << WGM02);

    } else if(prescaler == 64) {

        TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS01) | (1 << WGM02);

    } else if(prescaler == 256) {

        TCCR0B |= (1 << CS02) | (1 << WGM02);

    } else if(prescaler == 1024) {

         TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS02) | (1 << WGM02);

    } else {
        //Default prescaler
        TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS02) | (1 << WGM02);
    }

    TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);

    ttc = 255;

    OCR0A = 255;

    sei();
}
```

Comment: Setting `WGM02` to 1 in this function seems peculiar. The function doesn't appear to have anything to do with the Wave Generation Mode, and WGM = 100 is a reserved value.

Comment: Using `|=` may not be doing what you want. This will only change a bit from 0 to 1 and not from 1 to 0. If the `CS` values are already set (perhaps by the delay functionality) then this code will not change it back. You might want something like `TCC0RB = (TCC0RB & ~(1 << CS00 | 1 << CS01 | 1 << CS02)) | [the correct CS bits];`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Ill look into some of those changes. But any ideas on why the if() statement is not returning true? In the above code, if the pre-scaler is = to 1, then the LEDs on PortB should also turn on. Right before the if statements, for testing purposes, I manually set prescaler to 1. Therefore, the if(prescaler == 1) should return true. But it still doesn't. Any ideas?